# Doctrine and SQL Injection

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Does Doctrine automatically prevent SQL injection?
Is the following code secure?

```
$user = new Model_User();
$user->name = $_POST['username'];
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as SQL injection is concerned I think there will be no problem. But you might want to make sure as well that the username is well formed (could for instance be `<script>//do somthing bad</script>` and that script would for instance be executed when you output that user name somewhere on the site)

Answer (score 3):

You'll be safe from SQL injection with Doctrine (and any other PDO-based database library) as long as you use [bound parameters](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language%3aconditional-expressions%3ainput-parameters/en) (Doctrine will be using these under the hood so your example is fine), but you shouldn't ever use input from a client without sanitizing it first. Take a look at PHP's Filter library - in particular the sanitization example. In your case, you'd want to at least validate that the name is a string using FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING "Strip tags, optionally strip or encode special characters.".